# Split message telegram bot pyrogram

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, telegram-api, pyrogram

I have written an code to copy messages from source to destination chats used pyrogram python library. Code work fine, but its making absolute copy of messages from source chat.

Example of my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from pyrogram import Client
from pyrogram import filters

# ~~~~~~ CONFIG ~~~~~~~~ #
ACCOUNT = "@account"
PHONE_NR = 'number'

API_ID = APIID
API_HASH = "APIHASH"

app = Client( ACCOUNT, phone_number=PHONE_NR, api_id=API_ID, api_hash=API_HASH )

### CHAT ID

# Variables
SOURCE_CHAT_A = chat_id
TARGET_CHAT_A = chat_id
# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ #

# Commands
@app.on_message(filters.chat(SOURCE_CHAT_A))
def copy_to_channel(client, message):
    message.copy(  chat_id=TARGET_CHAT_A  ) 

app.run()
```

Is it possible to split message in pieces and print big messages from source chat as few small messages in destination chat?

For example, if it is message from source chat:

```
Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage 
Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage 
Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage 
Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage 

Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage 
Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage 
Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage
Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage  

Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage 
Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage 
Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage
Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage
```

Than in destination chat will come 3 separated messages:

```
Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage 
Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage 
Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage 
Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage
```

```
Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage 
Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage 
Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage 
Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage
```

```
Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage 
Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage 
Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage 
Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage Testmessage
```

My python level is absolutely not high enough, im sitting already a week with that problem and cant found a solution. Thanks for any type of help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you want to split on the double newline characters, you could do it like this:

```
@app.on_message(filters.chat(SOURCE_CHAT_A))
def copy_to_channel(client, message):
    # split message text on double newlines
    messages = message.text.split("\n\n")
    # send each message to the target chat
    for message in messages:
        client.send_message(TARGET_CHAT_A, message)
```

Or to split the message on 300 characters you can use [string](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_string_slice.asp) slicing. Loop on a [range](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_range.asp) that increments with 300 to get the starting index of each batch, then send the sliced string:

```
@app.on_message(filters.chat(SOURCE_CHAT_A))
def copy_to_channel(client, message):
    # split message into batches of 300 characters
    for i in range(0, len(message.text), 300):
        client.send_message(
            chat_id=SOURCE_CHAT_B,
            text=message.text[i:i+300]
        )
```

Comment: Thanks, you learned my something new mate. :) But is it possible to split message after x amount of strings or symbols? For example, if i set up 300 symbols for split, than if script get message with 500 symbols in total, than it will split it on 2 messages. 300 symbols in first one and 200 in second one.

Comment: @jamreg sure, see the updated answer

Comment: its exactly what i was looking for. Thanks a lot mate :)

Comment: one more question mate. len() worked perfect for the messages which doesn't have media content (photo,video,audio), but if there is media content in message, than i got an error `TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()`. I tried to add `if bool(message.photo) == True:` but it doesn't work as i excepted. Is it possible to make the code split every message? Thanks for your help mate :)

Comment: If the boolean doesn't work you could wrap it in try-except or add `filters.text` to `@app.on_message`: `@app.on_message(filters.text & filters.chat(SOURCE_CHAT_A))`

Comment: with `filters.text` i doesn't get error any more, but if message begin from a media content, than this messages will be just ignored. I tried to add `filters.photo` to the `filters` as well, but it actually changed nothing. My code is looking so far like that right now : I will add it as a next post, because comment's field is to short))

Comment: @jamreg make a new question out of it, not a comment

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70482332/split-message-with-media-content-and-without-telegram-pyrogram-bot